# Development of xcframework

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I'm interested in advice from the community. What do you think are the best practices when dealing with the development of an xcframework?

My question primarily concerns the development workflow's structure, specifically, the best way to set up your project so that you can build a sample app and observe changes in your framework.

There must be a cleaner and less cumbersome way to manage the xcframework development flow. From my research, it seems that using Swift Package Manager with a private repository could be a better solution, allowing me to run a script to create the xcframework when needed. However, I would appreciate hearing about other solutions or advice on the best approach when using SwiftPM.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Personally, I import the xcodeproj into the sample app and add MyFramework.framework instead of MyFramework.xcframework in the Frameworks XC settings. Once I've completed the development, I discard those changes and run a script to build a new xcframework.